# Pass python objects to ng-init angularjs

Tags: python, angularjs

in my views.py, i have

```
TaskNameList = Task.objects.all()
```

this is my detail.html

```
 77     <script src="{% static "angularjs-1.4.3/angular.min.js" %}"></script>
 78 
 79     <div ng-app="">
 80         <div ng-init="friends = {{ TaskNameList }}">
 81         </div>
 82     <label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
 83     <table id="searchTextResults">
 84         <tr><th>Name</th>
 85         <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
 86             <td>{$ friend.name $}</td>
 87         </tr>
 88     </div>
 89     </table>
```

i think I have a problem passing values from python to ng-int

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass *TaskNameList* as JSON from your view to your template. In your code *TaskNameList* is django's query and in template it'll become string representation of python list of classes (*Task* model instances).

If *Task* model has only JSON serializable attributes, you should be able to do something like this:

```
TaskNameList = json.dumps(list(Task.objects.all().values()))
```

Anyway, I think it's bad idea. It'll be much better to create REST API endpoint for *Task* model and then access it, using angular's ng-resource.